# How to add a next and previous link to current slider in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Well, I've been at this all day.  I'm a noob so its frustrating.  I wondering how do you add a previous and next link to the slider below.  I am wanting to do everything in pure javascript no jquery libraries.  Anyway here is the code.  I feel I tried everything.  This is so much easier in JQuery, but I need to learn pure javascript better.

```
<div id="container" onmouseover="stopFunc();" onmouseout="resumeFunc();">
   <img src="#" width="250px" height="145px" id="Box" style="margin: 15px;">
   <div id="imageDesc" style="margin: 15px;"></div>

   <a href="JavaScript:previousImage()" id="prevlink">Previous</a>
   <a href="JavaScript:nextImage()" id="nextlink">Next</a>

</div><!-- End container -->



<script type="text/javascript">
    var imageDescription = document.getElementById("imageDesc");
    var featureImg = document.getElementById("Box");

    var index = 0;

    var imageArray = [
        {src:"images/image1.jpg", des:"description1"},
        {src:"images/image2.jpg", des:"description2"},
        {src:"images/image3.jpg", des:"description3"},
        {src:"images/image4.jpg", des:"description4"}
        ];



    function newImage() {
        document.getElementById("container").style.visibility="visible";

        featureImg.setAttribute("src", imageArray[index].src);
        imageDescription.innerHTML = imageArray[index].des;

        index++;

        if (index >= imageArray.length) {
            index = 0;
        }

    }


    var myTimerControl = setInterval(function(){newImage()},3000);

    function stopFunc() {
        clearInterval(myTimerControl);
    }

    function resumeFunc() {
        myTimerControl = setInterval(function() {newImage()}, 3000);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, like I said JQuery is alot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little silly since it initializes with -1 but it works... Also note that there *is no* nextImage() function now, you simply reuse newImage()

```
<a href="JavaScript:newImage()" id="nextlink">Next</a>
```

...

```
var imageDescription = document.getElementById("imageDesc");
var featureImg = document.getElementById("Box");

var index = -1;

var imageArray = [
    {src:"images/image1.jpg", des:"description1"},
    {src:"images/image2.jpg", des:"description2"},
    {src:"images/image3.jpg", des:"description3"},
    {src:"images/image4.jpg", des:"description4"}
    ];

newImage();

function newImage() {

    index++;

    if (index >= imageArray.length) {
        index = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById("container").style.visibility="visible";

    featureImg.setAttribute("src", imageArray[index].src);
    imageDescription.innerHTML = imageArray[index].des;

}

function previousImage() {

    index--;

    if (index < 0) {
        index = imageArray.length-1;
    }

    featureImg.setAttribute("src", imageArray[index].src);
    imageDescription.innerHTML = imageArray[index].des;

}
```

It calls new image immediately which means you won't have to wait for the first timer run in order to see an image. You could also refactor a bit to make it much simpler but the main concept is --Incrementing/decrementing index before you display makes it clearer otherwise your current index value doesn't represent what's actually being shown.

Comment: I wonder why that is, I would of never thought to initialize to -1, just thought that would be silly.  I knew it was something simple.  I appreciate it, works like a charm.

Comment: Well the other way would be to set counter to 0 but have an initialization function that is separate from "newImage". The init version would just display & do that visibility setter without incrementing the index. if it worked like a dream plz mark my answer as chosen... haven't gotten one of those yet ;)